# Python list in list with 2 strings

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists of strings. I would like to combine them together to create list in lists like this one below.
`[['Hello','praet:sg:m1:perf'], ['world', 'subst:pl:acc:n']]`
How to do it? Somehow create instance of list in list or there is some "python magic"?

Thank you

Comment: what is ur input?

Comment: Two lists of strings. list1=['Hello', 'world'] , list2 = ['praet:sg:m1:perf','subst:pl:acc:n']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.

ex-1: by using '+'

```
list1=['Hello', 'world'] 
list2 = ['praet:sg:m1:perf','subst:pl:acc:n']

print([list1]+[list2])
```

ex-2: by using append()

```
res =[]
list1=['Hello', 'world'] 
list2 = ['praet:sg:m1:perf','subst:pl:acc:n']

res.append(list1)
res.append(list2)
print(res)
```

ex-3: by using zip()

```
list1=['Hello', 'world']
list2 = ['praet:sg:m1:perf','subst:pl:acc:n']

res = [[l1, l2] for l1,l2 in zip(list1, list2)]

print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

`zip` ([Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)) is what you are looking for. You can stitch together two lists in a list comprehension:

```
l1 = ['Hello', 'world']
l2 = ['praet:sg:m1:perf','subst:pl:acc:n']

zipped = [list(items) for items in zip(l1,l2)]

print(zipped)
```

Result:

```
[['Hello', 'praet:sg:m1:perf'], ['world', 'subst:pl:acc:n']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```
list1=['Hello', 'world']
list2 = ['praet:sg:m1:perf','subst:pl:acc:n']

newlist = []

for i in range(len(list1)):
   newlist.append([list1[i],list2[i]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the two list you have to another list:

```
list1 = ['Hello', 'praet:sg:m1:perf']
list2 = ['world', 'subst:pl:acc:n']

result = [list1, list2]
```

Another way:

```
result = []
list1 = ['Hello', 'praet:sg:m1:perf']
list2 = ['world', 'subst:pl:acc:n']

...

result.append(list1)
result.append(list2)
```

Comment: check the question once this not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip`

```
list1=['Hello', 'world']
list2 = ['praet:sg:m1:perf','subst:pl:acc:n']

result = [[x, y] for x,y in zip(list1, list2)]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['Hello', 'praet:sg:m1:perf'], ['world', 'subst:pl:acc:n']]
```